# Backup Outlook .pst file that is in use

Tags: outlook, xcopy, pst

I backup an Outlook .pst file on a client pc with a xcopy command to a Cloud storage account. Sometimes the user client has Outlook started and I can't copy the file because it is in use. Is there a way I can copy the file when Outlook has it opened and locked?

Answer (score 0):

Not using the regular Windows file API. AFAIK you can only do that using the backup file API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/backup/backup-functions)